# Android: how to have an animation on top of a background image

Tags: android, animation

What I'm trying to do is have a background image, for sake of simplicity, lets say it's a picture of the front of a house.  Then, I want to have a red ball move from  window to window.

**I want to have a background picture, and a picture on top of it.

**I then want to be able to tell the top picture EXACTLY where to go.

How can I do this?

I'm just beginning to learn about animations in Android, and have not yet run across any way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are two routes to animation in android: `Canvas` and OpenGL ES.
I would recommend OpenGL for anything requiring smoothness and speed, like a moving ball.
You should create a view using the helper class `GLSurfaceView`
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/introducing-glsurfaceview.html, and implement a `Renderer`.

I assume you have the images saved in your `res/drawable` folders, in a format like `png` and the ball file contains an alpha channel.

You can see many tutorials online, but basically you need to load your background image and your ball resource at `onSurfaceCreated` and store it in a texture using `GLUtils.texImage2D`.

In the `onDrawFrame` method, you should set up a 2D projection such as `glOrtho2D`, then draw the background.

Then just before you draw the ball texture, you can use the `glTranslate(x,y,0)` function to move the ball over the house. Use an alpha blend for the ball:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_SRC_ONE_MINUS_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
```

Unfortunately writing in OpenGL isn't as straightforward as you might hope. Everything is done with 3D coordinates, despite the fact you want only a 2D image. But hopefully this gives you enough info to google for good exmaples, which are abundant!